# MQTT:Delete undelivered messages

Tags: chat, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a requirement to delete undelivered messages,when client subscribe to topic.I just want to implement block/unblock functionality in my application.There are steps

```
1) Person "A" blocked person "B",now person B publishing messages to A and person A will not get messages.
```

Step 1 was simple and easily done.I am facing issue here in step 2

```
2) when person A unblocked person "B" and reconnect to topic,then it should not get previous messages send by person "B".
```

How can i do this,is there any way to clear messages of topic before subscribing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear a retained message on a topic by publishing a null payload.

But if you have persistent sessions there is no way to clear queued messages for a disconnected client.

EDIT:
I think the only way to do what you want would be to change a ACL of which users could subscribe to what topics. ACLs are all broker dependant.